# How can I create a 3d object/class in Python?

Tags: python, 3d

My end goal right now is to take points that are read from a text file, and turn them into 3d objects.  They do not need to be visualized, but they need to be stored in objects instead of just a string containing the x, y, and z values.  The file gives me six numbers, two of each x, y, and z, and I was wondering how I would go about creating a point class/object that will take all three variables and then a line object/class that will take two of the points.

Comment: do you want to show the 3D object, or just store it?

Comment: Converting strings to numbers is trivial. So is defining two classes `Point3D(x, y, z)` and `Line(point1, point2)`. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I've written a tutorial which pretty much does what you want: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-3d-graphics-tutorial/nodes-and-edges

Comment: It's part of a research thing I'm doing.  I'm doing it step by step and this is what my professor asked for, so I'm just going to do it up like this.

Comment: @marcinx27, please don't edit the question to make it completelly different. If you still have doubts about something, post a new question

Comment: @marcinx27, just to avoid you asking again, you could check that your code was working doing `print edges`, that way, you can see how your list of edges is growing

Answer (score 7):

Just define a `Point` and a `Line` class:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0 ,z=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class Line(object):
    def __init__(self, point1=None, point2=None):
        self.point1 = point1 or Point() # (0,0,0) by default
        self.point2 = point2 or Point() # (0,0,0) by default
```

To create points and lines objects:

```
>>> p1 = Point(1, 2, 3)
>>> p2 = Point(4, 5, 6)
>>> line = Line(p1, p2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have got the data from the file (for this Regular Expressions are applicable), you will want to input that into a class which is defined as to store the two points (which can be objects themselves) e.g.

```
class Point(tuple):
    @property
    def x:
        return self[0]

    @property
    def y:
        return self[1]

    @property
    def z:
        return self[2]

class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2):
        self._a = Point(x1, y1, z1)
        self._b = Point(x2, y2, z2)

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    # Other methods here e.g.

    @property
    def i(self):
        return self.b.x - self.a.x

    @property
    def j(self):
        return self.b.y - self.a.y

    @property
    def k(self):
        return self.b.z - self.a.z

    def length(self):
        return ( self.i**2 + self.j**2 + self.k**2 ) ** (1/2)
```